# Relative Path, usable in both Console Application and ASP.NET Webapplication

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to specify a path that is relative to the root of both a console and an asp.net webapplication? So

- For the Console Application, it should be relative to the .exe file
- For the ASP.NET Webapplication, it should be relative to the root Web.Config

Example: Let's say I have a file called "log.txt". I have a logging component in a separate dll, that uses this log.txt under "logs" folder. I have two applications that use this component, one is a Console Application, the other one is an ASP.NET Web Application.

Is it possible to specify a relative path in the logging component, that will find the file at the following places?:

**mywebapp/**
-Web.Config
-bin/logging.dll
-other web files
-logs/**log.txt**

**myconsoleapp/**
-myconsoleapp.exe
-logging.dll
-some other dlls
-logs/**log.txt**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

Reference:

- Accepted answer of [ASP.NET Relative Paths in Referenced Libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798814/asp-net-relative-paths-in-referenced-libraries?rq=1)
- Second answer of [How can I get the application's path in a .NET console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/837488/how-can-i-get-the-applications-path-in-a-net-console-application)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a little change:

Don't determine the path of your log within your logging component. Make it as a parameter. On the webàpplication you can use `Server.MapPath` ([MSDN Server.MapPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)) to map relative to absolute paths.

Comment: That's my only idea too. Too bad that my problem is a lot more complex, this logging thing was just an example (I actually try to find multiple custom config files for multiple components). I can't accept this, since it's not an answer to my question, but I'll still give an upvote  for it.

Comment: What's within your reach? Can you make changes within these components? And what webapplication? WCF?ASP?

Comment: I can make changes in the component, and it's an ASP.NET application.